# AngularJS :: Drag-drop with auto-select options

Tags: jquery, angularjs, drag-and-drop

I am implementing email compose like feature of gmail in my angular application.

I need to drag-drop contacts between TO and CC fields and also TO/CC fields have auto select dropdown option for selecting contacts.

I am unable to find solution for this, so anyone please suggest me jquery/angular plugin which I can use for this feature.

Thanks in adavance!

Answer (score 0):

Straight from angularJs's developer guide will take care of the dragging part

```
    angular.module('dragModule', [])
.directive('myDraggable', ['$document', function($document) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      var startX = 0, startY = 0, x = 0, y = 0;

      element.css({
       position: 'relative',
       border: '1px solid red',
       backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
       cursor: 'pointer'
      });

      element.on('mousedown', function(event) {
        // Prevent default dragging of selected content
        event.preventDefault();
        startX = event.pageX - x;
        startY = event.pageY - y;
        $document.on('mousemove', mousemove);
        $document.on('mouseup', mouseup);
      });

      function mousemove(event) {
        y = event.pageY - startY;
        x = event.pageX - startX;
        element.css({
          top: y + 'px',
          left:  x + 'px'
        });
      }

      function mouseup() {
        $document.off('mousemove', mousemove);
        $document.off('mouseup', mouseup);
      }
    }
  };
}]);
```

I'm not sure how you could know which text field you mouseup() in, but some logic in mouseup() would set scope values.